# Changing network interface at runtime

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, wireless, broadband

I am programming a small application with qt5. This application gets the reply from an API server every minute. Every thing is working fine but I ran into a bug.

While testing the application I found that if my wireless is disconnected and reconnected again the application will work fine. Also if I use my broadband connection and the connection is disconnected and reconnected again every thing works fine also. Now if I use my wireless at application startup then I disconnect the wireless and connect my broadband the program won't see the broadband connection and keeps giving me network error.

I use a single `QNetworkAccessManager` instance for the connection. The interesting thing is that If I created a new `QNetworkAccessManager` instance for each request the application will work fine. But I think there will be overhead in declaring a new instance for each request and making connections. I tried also to use `clearAccessCache()` before the request with no luck.

So basically I am looking for some thing to reset `QNetworkAccessManager` with each request. Here is a sample code of my request:

```
// At class construct
manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
// ....
// At member function
url = new QUrl("http://www.gridstatusnow.com/status");
manager->get(QNetworkRequest(*url));
```

Comment: "But I think there will be overhead in declaring a new instance for each request"  why not verify that first? Guessing is usually not a good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to recreate the `QNetworkAccessManager` only if network is not accessible:

```
// At member function
if (manager->networkAccessible() == QNetworkAccessManager::NotAccessible)
{
    delete manager;
    manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
}
```

[The documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#networkAccessible-prop) explains:

> By default the value of this property reflects the physical state of the device.